# How do I go to home page when i refresh a page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to refresh react website and I want to show an alert and if user check confirm the website is going to home page with route whenever refresh my website.
so, I tried to use `onbeforeunload` but it's not what i expected .
This is what im using, but when i refresh then it can't go to home page

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      return true;
    };
    return () => {
      window.onbeforeunload = null;
    };
  }, []);
```

I'd like to know how to go to home page when i refresh a page.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try not to do so. This is a poor user experience.

Comment: It would be a very bad experience for the customer, can you explain why you need to do so?

Comment: It's because there is csv file upload and i can't get uploaded csv file in localstorage when it refresh so I tried to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const beforeunloadHandle = () => {
    return true;
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeunloadHandle);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("removeEventListener", beforeunloadHandle);
  };
}, []);
```